# What is an up-vote worth in reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, upvotes

Today, I got two upvotes on the same thing (which was several months old).  One of them gave me ten points and the other five points.  Why is that?

P.S. "Related" is not the same as "duplicate," and "What is an upvote worth?" is not the same as "why did rep change and can I edit it?"

Comment: Your edit is wrong.  The answer to you specific "what is an upvote worth" is completely answered in the answer to the  more general question "Why did I gain/lose reputation".  If you don't think it answers your question, then edit your question and explain why it doesn't address your question and why you are still confused

Comment: The answer is in there, yes.  The question was not duplicate until I edited the other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You got votes on **two separate posts**. Your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456900/how-to-make-an-excel-data-connection-without-a-dsn) *and* [your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456900/how-to-make-an-excel-data-connection-without-a-dsn/17678320#17678320) on that question were upvoted.

Question upvotes give you +5 points, answer upvotes earn you +10. See the [*You gain reputation when:* section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) in the help center.

In [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854073/wgroleau?tab=reputation&sort=time), apart from the point difference, you can tell question and answer votes apart by their colour:

[image: question and answer votes]

The question is displayed in blue, while your answer is rendered in black text.

Comment: Which does not help if one has multiple answers at the same question: In that case, test the link.

Answer (score 4):

Upvotes on questions give 5 rep, upvotes on answers give 10.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer; why downvote?  Sure, the other one is more detailed, but likely neither person saw the other, since they posted a minute apart.